# Canceling event bubbling on specific elements - javascript

Tags: javascript, dhtml

Basically, I want to make clicking anywhere on a page except in an input field and on one block level element (an by extension all children there in) erase said input field.  So I put an onclick event on the whole document.  To keep the conditions above I put conditions before the clear instructions to only do it if the event did not arise from specific elements.

```
clearSearch = function (e){
 e ? e : e = window.event;
 e.target ? target = e.target : target = e.srcElement;
 if (target.nodeName != "INPUT" && document.getElementById('ul'))
 document.getElementById('input').value = "";
}
```

With this method if I want to keep clicking on the ul from causing the action I have to explicitly state it in this if statement.  Then I have to do the same for the li elements under the ul.  Then any other children I create.

Basically this seems really inefficient and I was wondering if someone could help me out in thinking up a better solution to this mess I have created for myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the complex logic from `clearSearch` and just have it clear the search box. Then add some new onClick handlers to the elements you don't want to call this method. In those handlers set `event.cancelBubble` to true to prevent the clearSearch function being called.

From [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html):

```
For a complete cross-browser experience do:

function doSomething(e)
{
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Right, but do I have to do it on each element or does cancel bubble on the ul take care of all it's child elements?

Comment: @sobertilnoon: If you stop event bubbling on the <ul>, it will also work for all its list items.

Comment: yeah, I just have to make sure that the event is in bubble mode not capture mode.  worked once I realized I put true not false.  thanks.